# Android MapView does not load unless you touch on the mapview

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have added a mapview in my android application.I have used correct settings in the manifest and now i'm facing a problem. When i go to the place where i have my map,it displays only the canvas but not the map. If i touch on it only it starts loading. Even then it does not fully load.it loads only to a certain level.if i keep touching the screen it continuously loads. But even then i cannot zoom in or out OR cant even move the map. Is there a solution for this? Have i done something wrong?

My Code

```
            MapView mapView;
            GoogleMap map;





             mapView = (MapView)view.findViewById(R.id.map);
             Bundle savedInstanceState = null;
            mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
                map = mapView.getMap();
                map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                MapsInitializer.initialize(activity);

                double lat;
                double lon;

                lat = Double.parseDouble(theaterDetail.getLatitude());
                lon = Double.parseDouble(theaterDetail.getLongitude());

                // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(lat, lon)).title(theaterDetail.getAddress()));

                final LatLng THEATER_POSITION = new LatLng(lat, lon);

                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(THEATER_POSITION) // Sets the center of the map to
                                                    // THEATER_POSITION
                        .zoom(10) // Sets the zoom
                        .bearing(360) // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                        .tilt(30) // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                        .build(); // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
                        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView 
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.***.***"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"
        />

     <permission
    android:name="com.***.***.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

     <uses-permission android:name="com.***.***.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />






    <application
        android:name="com.***.***.service.CommonVariable"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


        <!-- <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />  --> 

        <activity
            android:name="com.***.***.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" 
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        </activity>

        <activity 
             android:name="com.***.***.Map"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar" ></activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.***.***.WelcomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.NoActionBar"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                    android:value="*********************" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Above code in java class, on which function you are writing? and why you are calling this function mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);?

Comment: my mapview code is placed inside a asyncTask and i'm calling it like this.


  if (page == Element.THEATER_DETAIL.getType()) {

   view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filmhall, container, false);

   Theater theater = (Theater) item.get(position);
   
   
   
   

   new BackGround((theater.getTheaterId()),view).execute();
   
  }

Comment: @EagleEye do you have a solution?

Comment: Can you move this code  mapView = (MapView)view.findViewById(R.id.map);
             Bundle savedInstanceState = null;
            mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
                map = mapView.getMap();
                map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); to onPreExecute() and check?

Comment: did not work :( app just crashed

Comment: refer this. https://gist.github.com/joshdholtz/4522551 This will be helpfull

Comment: thank you.But this is the tutorial i referred in the first place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68635/discussion-between-eagleeye-and-crazydroid).

Comment: Just add mapView.onResume() - I spent about 5 hours to find out that =)

Comment: yes that was the answer..i figured that after hours of trying..anyways thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Though this is an old question, I am providing here what worked for me. The reason that this solution works is that it overrides the onResume() handler. If you are using a mapView, you need to call mapView.onResume() from the onResume() handler. Example:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    mMapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: You are my hero! This was exactly the solution I needed for the above problem!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Also note that you need to hook into onPause() and onLowMemory() methods. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

**Java File**

```
package com.dilip.googlemapsv2;

import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    /**
    * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
    * */
   private void initilizeMap() {
       if (googleMap == null) {
           //googleMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
           googleMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

           // check if map is created successfully or not
           if (googleMap == null) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this.getApplicationContext());
       initilizeMap();
   }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**XML Page Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"

        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"      
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

**Mainfest File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dilip.googlemapsv2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <permission
        android:name="com.dilip.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.dilip.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />



            <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
                 android:required="true"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Goolge API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />                /* Added Bi Dilip */ 
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you are using MapFragment.. i'm doing a MapView

Comment: Both Way we can do but in the Fragment way is easy to as compare mapview and load fast as much map view....