# Google Maps show gray on android device

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps

I have Google map implemented into my app (in fragment) when I open that fragment it just show gray screen while I am getting correct latitude, longitude

## Code

```
override fun onCreateView(
  inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
  savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
  // Inflate the layout for this fragment
  val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_to_customer, container, false)
  customerAddressArgument = requireArguments().getString("customerAddressArgument").toString()
  // Google Maps
  var mapView = root.findViewById(R.id.map) as MapView
  mapView.getMapAsync(this)
  mapView.onCreate(arguments)
  return root
}

override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
  mMap = googleMap
  // mMap.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true

  val geoCoder = Geocoder(context)
  var address = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(customerAddressArgument, 1)!![0]
  val latLng = LatLng(address.latitude, address.longitude)
  mMap!!.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Location"))
  mMap!!.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng))
  Log.d("latLng20:", latLng.toString()) <-- return: **D/latLng20:: lat/lng: (-6.3946055,106.7947916)**
  Toast.makeText(
    context,
    address.latitude.toString() + " " + address.longitude,
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
  ).show()
}
```

`latLng` in google [maps website](https://www.google.com/maps/place/6%C2%B023%2740.6%22S+106%C2%B047%2741.3%22E/@-6.3946055,106.7947916,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d-6.3946055!4d106.7947916)

**Any idea?**

Comment: what is `mapView.onCreate(arguments)`, I don't find it in the docs?

Comment: @PavelPoley without that map will not be loaded

Comment: is your map sdk enabled?

Comment: @UsamaAltaf yes I guess so, but to be sure where should I check it?

Comment: https://console.developers.google.com/ here

Comment: @UsamaAltaf yes there is enabled.

Comment: what is your logcat showing?

Comment: @UsamaAltaf `Log.d("latLng20:", latLng.toString()) <-- return: **D/latLng20:: lat/lng: (-6.3946055,106.7947916)**`

Comment: @UsamaAltaf apparently map will not load until I touch screen several times! any idea how to fix that?

Comment: map will load after you touch screen several times?

Comment: yes, strange right :))

Comment: are you trying in real device or emulator? what is the version of android?

Comment: trying on real device, android 10

Comment: @UsamaAltaf I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34603597/8490993) but it's red on `mMap.onResume()` part for me

Comment: @mafortis But How  :)

Comment: I'm sharing the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The issue

During debugging process I found out that my map needs tapping on screen in order to load each individual part of it and it does not load elements by itself.

#### Solution

To fix the issue I've found and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34603597/8490993) that suggested to use `onResume()` function in order to load maps and here is how it's done.

```
var mapView: MapView? = null //<-- add this

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_to_customer, container, false)
        customerAddressArgument = requireArguments().getString("customerAddressArgument").toString()

        // Google Maps
        mapView = root.findViewById(R.id.map) as MapView //<- define it here
        mapView!!.getMapAsync(this)
        mapView!!.onCreate(arguments)
        return root
}

override fun onResume() {
  mapView?.onResume() //<- get it in onResume()
  super.onResume()
}
```

And problem solved.